# Does SemaphoreSlim guarantee entry when there are constantly more than one callers waiting for entry

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, locking, semaphore

Say I have a SemaphoreSlim limiting concurrent calls to an external API like this:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendApiRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    using (await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync())
        return await SendRequestToAPI(request);
}
```

If the number of calls to the API is such that there is no long-time build up waiting callers but there are still at least two callers waiting at all times, are all callers guaranteed to be let through eventually? Or could one request be "unlucky" and never be picked for entry when another caller releases the semaphore?

Comment: If you're interested as to *why* `SemaphoreSlim` (and other sync primitives) is not "fair", [have a read of this article by Joe Duffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/).

Comment: You are missing a call to release... so your calls are bound to wait forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8):

> If multiple threads are blocked, there is no guaranteed order, such as
>   FIFO or LIFO, that controls when threads enter the semaphore.

So yes, one request could be unlucky and never get picked.

Comment: This is not accurate.  The documentation is stating that the order is not guaranteed.... It is not saying that the the semaphore "can lose" some requests along the way.